# Should I assist or deter birds from a popular yet problematic location?

Tags: trees, birds

For three years in a row a [nest has fallen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82CLV.jpg) from this tree in my backyard the last weekend of April.  The prior 2 years were robins but this year it was [something new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odxdP.jpg).  Not knowing birds well but generally being a fan what is the best way to end this cycle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about birds, not plants. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: It is nothing you've done HireThisMarine!  This is life and death for birds.  Process of evolution.  Gosh this last nest looks like Mocking Bird? https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=birds+eggs&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F9%2F95%2FMocking_Bird_eggs.JPG#id=3&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F9%2F95%2FMocking_Bird_eggs.JPG&action=click

Comment: @stormy There is a fork in branches that they seem to think is a steady foundation, I think I'll surgically trim so that they have one less false-positive when they are shopping for homes.

Comment: You doll.  A Marine with a huge heart.  Just wanna give you a major hugg!  That sounds like a  plan.  Thanks so very much for making MY day...